# Two implementation for signal in scala - one fires an event on text change and other doesnot

Tags: scala, functional-programming, reactive-programming

I have to implement a function which takes signal of remaining char count to compute the signal of color i.e.

- If there are 15 or more characters left, the color "green"
- If there are between 0 and 14 characters left, included, the color "orange"
- Otherwise (if the remaining count is negative), the color "red"

I have implemented this in following way:

```
remainingCharsCount() match {
  case x if x < 0 => Signal("red")
  case x if x >= 14 =>  Signal("green")
  case _ =>  Signal("orange")
}
```

where `remainingCharsCount: Signal[Int]` is a signal of remaining characters in a text.

The problem with the implementation above is that it does not fire events for color change based on remaining text count. In other implementations, I have moved the logic for color change inside the Signal block.

This code works fine:

```
Signal {
  val rc = remainingCharsCount()
  if (rc >= 15) "green"
  else if (rc >= 0) "orange"
  else "red"
}
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong in the first implementation?

For more info you can refer this link: https://github.com/ujjkumsi/FPDesign/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first approach, `remainingCharsCount()` is called once using which the pattern matching result is evaluated.

In the second approach, everything happens inside a `Signal` block.
In `Signal { block }`, `block` is the code which gets evaluated when dependencies change.
The dependencies are created by the signals been used inside the callers.

For example: `remainingCharsCount()` adds the `caller`, the `returned Signal` in your case to it's observers.

See the `apply()` method in: https://github.com/omirho/scalafun2/blob/master/calculator/src/main/scala/calculator/Signal.scala

Also see the other method implementations.

Let me explain this a little more.
In approach 1:

`remainingCharsCount()` gets evaluated and gets assigned to a value. And the outer signal (which can't be seen in this code and can be treated as `nil`) gets added to its observers. 
The value is then used for pattern matching to construct a constant `Signal`.
Hence, the required dependency is not created.

Approach 2 has been explained before.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do this

```
Signal(remainingCharsCount() match {
      case x if x >= 15 => "green"
      case x if x >= 0 => "orange"
      case _ =>"red"
    })
```

Signal need dependencies inside it expression to observe changes.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 0):

I have no access to you link. But as I remember `Signal` takes a block of code that is executed each time the input is changed. 
In your first approach `remainingCharsCount()` is called only once (when you declare the signal). In the second it is called (by a framework) while something has changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated the link.
Still, I can't understand why in first implementation it is called only once. Since I am changing characters and my remainingCharCount is signal which will cause remainingCharsCount() value to get changed causing new declaration of signal